How to find if an ID appears in each group?
I have a dataset that includes variables such as recordID (e.g. 1104, 4406), deposit (e.g. 100, 124), and month (e.g. 01, 02, 03, etc.). I want to find out how many of these recordIDs are making regularly deposits, as in they have made a deposit at least once every month.
Is there an easy way to do this in R? Maybe using dplyr::group_by?
Reproducible example:
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(recordID = sample(100:110, 300, replace = TRUE),
                  month = sample(1:12, 300, replace = TRUE), 
                  deposit=sample(10:500, 300, replace=TRUE))


Please don't delete your question to post a new one. You'll get question banned. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318551/my-question-has-a-negative-score-and-no-answers-should-i-delete-it (Link to the deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78755397/how-to-find-if-an-id-appears-in-each-group-in-r#78755397)

For future reference, you should always provide a minimal reproducible example of your code and data along with relevant errors. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question. The links here guide you on how to achieve that. Cheers.

You can do this:
library(dplyr)

filter(dat, n_distinct(month) == 12, .by = recordID)


This doesn't seem to work for me, I get the error: Error: Problem with filter() input ..2.
x Input ..2 is named.
i This usually means that you've used = instead of ==.   .. After changing it to == i then get the error object '.by' not found

This isn't clear from the OP, but a record might only have data Feb - July if they, for example, opened the account in Feb. Something the OP could clarify -- if this were the case should they be counted as regularly depositing? (+1 since this does answer their posted question).

@user17753, the .by argument to filter() was added in dplyr version 1.1.0. What version are you using? Run packageVersion('dplyr') to find out.

@LMc is correct, some accounts would only have data from Feb- July if they opened an account in Feb which I should've specified. They should still be classed as regularly depositing if they've made a payment in every month from Feb-July. I'm also running version 1.0.6, and I can't update it either.

Then you can remove the .by argument and add the group_by() to the pipe chain: dat |> group_by(recordID) |> filter(n_distinct(month) == 12) |> ungroup()

@LMc This doesn't work either for me and just creates an empty tibble. Could you tell me what each bit of the code is meant to do?

@user17753 if that does not work for you then I would say your example reproducible data is not sufficient enough and you need to spend more time creating a fake data set that more closely mimics the intricacies of your data. You have the most information and we can only provide solutions based on what you provide in your post. Simply saying "This doesn't work" does not provide us any information on why it does not work. I would recommend spending more time thinking about what exactly you need and what information we need to provide a solution. For the time being I am going to vote to close.

The posted code keeps record IDs that have at least one deposit in every month of the year.

@user17753 Based on what you described, as LMC mentioned, your toy dataset is not sufficient to reproduce the behavior. I suspect that you have actual dates, and not just month numbers. What if a client has opened an account in November last year, and has orders for each month till July this year? And is it possible to have multiple orders per month or not?  You basically wanna check if there's a gap in orders, right?
